# SharePoint/Linq error on Update Lookup Field (Specified cast is not valid)?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have two lists called "Department" and "Employee", in Employee has a lookup employee depart to the "Department" list

I need to know how can I do the update Employee information and department column by using linq to SharePoint?

Please advice.!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var result = ((from item in web.Lists["Employee"].Items.Cast<SPListItem>()  // Change Employee list name
              from deptitem in web.Lists["Department"].Items.Cast<SPListItem>() // Change Department list name
               where item.ID == 50 && deptitem.Title == "Dept2"   // Department title which you want to update
                    select new {  item, deptitem }).All(x =>
                    {
                         x.item["Title"] = "Updated";
                         x.item["Department"] = x.deptitem.ID;
                         x.item.Update();
                         return true;
                     }));
```